# A smooth family of lattices on the tangent bundle?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, vector-bundles, foliations, tangent-distributions

I was recently in the cafeteria with a friend, and while having lunch I explained to him why the tangent bundle of a manifold is good at encoding geometric information of the manifold. My second example was Foliations and the Frobenius theorem. I described to him the tangent sub-bundles etc.
After carefully listening, he shot back with the question “How a smoothly varying family of lattices on the tangent bundle would reflect on the manifold?”.
Here a lattice means a discrete additive subgroup $\Gamma$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\mathbb{R}^n/\Gamma$ is compact.

I couldn’t think of a reasonable explanation for this off the top of my head, and a quick Google search did not show anything related. In fact, I do not see a reasonable motivation for somebody to ask this question at all. Anyway, I thought of posting it as a question here, and see the opinions from the experts.

Comment: 1)I guess there is a typo somewhere in  "how would a smoothly varying family of lattices on the tangent bundle would reflect on the manifold?"
2) what example triggered your friend? What would be the lattice associated to a k-plane distribution?

Comment: This is just free association to an open-ended question. If just consider vector bundles, not just the tangent bundle, the simplest example is a bundle with fiber $\mathbb{R}$ with the $\mathbb{Z}$ lattice included in each fiber. Quotienting the fibers by the lattice, you get a [circle bundle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_bundle). In fact this is a convenient way to classify and construct characteristic classes of circle bundles. I imagine something analogous could be said about more general bundles with fiber $\mathbb{R}^n/\Gamma$.

Comment: In symplectic geometry and mirror symmetry, you can find a lot of literature on manifolds with an "integral affine structure". This means that they have an atlas where all transition maps are of the form $x \mapsto Ax+b$, for $A \in \text{GL}_n(\mathbb{Z})$ and $b \in \mathbb{R}^n$. This turns out to be equivalent to asking that $M$ is the base of a "Lagrangian torus fibration", meaning that there is a $2n$-dimensional symplectic manifold $X$ with a submersion $X \to M$ are all of fibers are $n$-dimensional tori on which the $2$-form vanishes. (continued)

Comment: Both of these conditions are stronger than simply asking for a family of lattices though. Let $M  = \mathbb{R}^n$ and consider a family $L$ of lattices in $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$; put $X = \mathbb{R}^{2n}/L$. Then $X \to M$ is always a torus fibration, but the standard $2$-form on $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ will not usually descend to $X$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A choice of a (smoothly varying) lattice in each tangent space is the same as a reduction of structure group of the tangent bundle from $GL_n(\mathbb R)$ to $GL_n(\mathbb Z)$. For instance, it implies the existence of a flat connection, so by Chern-Weil theory all rational characteristic classes vanish. In general, there is a sequence of iteratively defined obstructions valued in the homotopy groups $\pi_k(GL_n(\mathbb R)/GL_n(\mathbb Z))$ of the fiber of the map $BGL_n(\mathbb Z)\to BGL_n(\mathbb R)$ along which you want to lift the classifying map of the tangent bundle.

Comment: You may want to mention as an example that the existence of a flat connection implies also that if the manifold is simply-connected then the tangent bundle is trivial.

Answer (score 5):

A smooth family of lattices cannot in general be chosen in the tangent bundle of a manifold, even in such a simple case as $S^2$.  Indeed, if one could do this it would imply that one can also choose a nowhere vanishing tangent vector field on $S^2$, which is [known not to exist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hairy_ball_theorem).